# Проблемы с youtube видео на сайте

Tags: html, видео, youtube

При воспроизведении видео на сайте появляется непонятная кнопка, дойдя до которой видео ставится на паузу. На основном сайте youtube, куда ссылается линк с сайта ничего подобного нету. При наведении курсором появляется надпись: просмотреть видео полностью. Какие бы ссылки я не вставлял - появляется это ограничение в минуту. Кто-то сталкивался с подобным и знает как избавиться от этого ограничения в минуту?

Пример html кода:

```
<a class="quelle-video--link" id="video2316" video-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kbLQPlrujW8" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это задаётся параметром «end» в ссылке ифрейма https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Как избавиться — убрать этот «end» из ссылки, только вот кто его ставит в вашем случае — непонятно (по умочланию ничего такого нет)